# ASP Classic Page doesn't finish loading on submit

Tags: asp-classic

I have an ASP Classic page that loads correctly on first load. 
When the user click the Delete button on the page it runs a COM which updates a number of records in the database, and then displays a message telling the user the delete has completed.

However, if I have a large number of users to update, 5000 or more, after the COM update runs the message telling the user the delete has completed never appears. It's almost like the page never finishes loading after the submit fires.

I put a Server.ScriptTimeout of 1 hour on the page so it would have plenty of time to finish the COM processing. But I notice that when updating a large number of records, the page will process until the 1 hour is complete even though the update only took 10-15 minutes to run. Then the message never appears telling the user it has completed.

Any ideas what I have going on here?

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: My first assumption is some internal timeout in the COM handler. Can you post some code please and also explain what COM exactly you're using?

Comment: Please show us some code